# PHP: fopen: file access queued by default?

Tags: php, fopen, file-access

User A is accessing the file x.txt and user B tries to do the same. How will the script react?

Comment: Please see [stackoverflow.com/PHP Simultaneous File Writes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209688/php-simultaneous-file-writes).